# Convert Wide to Long with frequency column

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

I am trying to convert my data.frame from a wide table to a long table with a frequency column.

```
data("UCBAdmissions")
ucb_admit <- as.data.frame(UCBAdmissions)
ucb_admit
   Admit    Gender Dept Freq
1  Admitted   Male    A  512
2  Rejected   Male    A  313
3  Admitted Female    A   89
4  Rejected Female    A   19
...
```

And I want to gather this data (tidyr package, similar to melt from reshape) but use the Freq to specify how many times the row should be repeated.

My target data would therefore look something like:

```
     Admit      Gender Dept
1    Admitted   Male    A
2    Admitted   Male    A
3    Admitted   Male    A
4    Admitted   Male    A
5    Admitted   Male    A
6    Admitted   Male    A
...
4523 Rejected Female    F
4524 Rejected Female    F
4525 Rejected Female    F
4526 Rejected Female    F
```

I would like to use the tidyr::gather() to do this, however my results are not correct as I am unsure if/how to include the Freq column?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't look like a job for `gather` as the data are aggregated, rather than wide. You can "disaggregate" the data using indexing by repeating the row indices `Freq` times for each row. Below are methods using base R and `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

# Base R
ucb_admit_disagg = ucb_admit[rep(1:nrow(ucb_admit), ucb_admit$Freq), 
                             -grep("Freq", names(ucb_admit))]

# dplyr
ucb_admit_disagg = ucb_admit %>% 
  slice(rep(1:n(), Freq)) %>% 
  select(-Freq)
```

Here's a portion of the data frame. I've added ellipses to the output to mark breaks in the row sequence.

```
ucb_admit_disagg[c(1:6, 510:514, 4523:4526), ]
```

> ```
>           Admit Gender Dept
> 1      Admitted   Male    A
> 1.1    Admitted   Male    A
> 1.2    Admitted   Male    A
> 1.3    Admitted   Male    A
> 1.4    Admitted   Male    A
> 1.5    Admitted   Male    A
> ...
> 1.509  Admitted   Male    A
> 1.510  Admitted   Male    A
> 1.511  Admitted   Male    A
> 2      Rejected   Male    A
> 2.1    Rejected   Male    A
> ...
> 24.313 Rejected Female    F
> 24.314 Rejected Female    F
> 24.315 Rejected Female    F
> 24.316 Rejected Female    F
> ```

Comment: Very nice solutions. I did a microbenchmarking to compare the two methods proposed  by you and three methods proposed by me. The result shows that both of your methods are faster than mine, and base R is the fastest.

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you.  I went with the base R method as @ycw suggested based on the benchmarking

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `dplyr`, `tidyr`, and `purrr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

ucb_admit2 <- ucb_admit %>%
  mutate(Freq = map2(1, Freq, `:`)) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  select(-Freq)
```

Or use this similar approach, which only needs functions from `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

```
ucb_admit2 <- ucb_admit %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Freq = list(seq(1, Freq))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  unnest() %>%
  select(-Freq)
```

Both of them adopt the same strategy: create a list column and then `unnest` it.

We can also consider use the `separate_row` function from `tidyr` to achieve this task.

```
ucb_admit2 <- ucb_admit %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Freq = paste(seq(1, Freq), collapse = ",")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  separate_rows(Freq) %>%
  select(-Freq)
```

#### Benchmarking

I compared the two methods proposed by eipi10 and the three methods proposed by me, using the following `microbenchmarking`. The result shows that base R approach is the fastest, followed by the `dplyr` repeat and slice approach. So, I think unless there are other considerations, such as code readability, no need to use `tidyr` or `purrr` for this question.

```
library(microbenchmark)

library(microbenchmark)


microbenchmark(m1 = (ucb_admit[rep(1:nrow(ucb_admit), 
                                   ucb_admit$Freq), 
                               -grep("Freq", names(ucb_admit))]),
               m2 = (ucb_admit %>% 
                       slice(rep(1:n(), Freq)) %>% 
                       select(-Freq)),
               m3 = (ucb_admit %>%
                       mutate(Freq = map2(1, Freq, `:`)) %>%
                       unnest() %>%
                       select(-Freq)),
               m4 = (ucb_admit %>%
                       rowwise() %>%
                       mutate(Freq = list(seq(1, Freq))) %>%
                       ungroup() %>%
                       unnest() %>%
                       select(-Freq)),
               m5 = (ucb_admit %>%
                       rowwise() %>%
                       mutate(Freq = paste(seq(1, Freq), collapse = ",")) %>%
                       ungroup() %>%
                       separate_rows(Freq) %>%
                       select(-Freq)))

Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
   m1  3.455026  3.585888  4.295322  3.845367  4.147506   8.60228   100
   m2  6.888881  7.541269  8.849527  8.031040  9.428189  15.53991   100
   m3 23.252458 24.959122 29.706875 27.414396 32.506805  61.00691   100
   m4 20.033499 21.914645 25.888155 23.611688 27.310155 101.15088   100
   m5 28.972557 31.127297 35.976468 32.652422 37.669135  64.43884   100
```

Comment: I went with the base R method as the benchmarks suggested.  I knew there was more than one way to skin a cat but it would have taken me a while to come up with 5!  Thanks!